# Browser not showing code change after cache refreshed

Tags: html, browser, server

Okay, before someone answers, note the following:

1. Refreshed Browser Cache 10-11 times
2. Added No-Cache Headers
3. I am definitely working on the correct file & directory
4. Tried on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge.
5. Restarted droplet 3-4 times
6. Waited for 2 hours (If propagation delay)
7. Pure HTML. No PHP or any server script.
8. Using an Apache Server
9. Uploaded using FileZilla, WebStorm's Upload, and directly from the terminal as well.

When I make an update in the code and upload it on the server, and view the code on NANO, it shows the updated code. If I download the code and view it on ATOM, it shows the code. If I open the downloaded file on any browser, the developer console doesn't show the change. Even online, it doesn't show.

If I remove that element completely, it doesn't disappear. When I remove the whole body, or delete the file itself, the browser shows 404 or removes the whole body.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the file is not updated correctly on your Apache(?) server. You probably need to add more details about how the file is sent from the server to the browser (what server do you use, etc.)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 - Apache Server. Uploaded using FileZilla, then tried the same from WebStorm. Then ended up trying the same directly from the terminal.